# Rename/Refactor database elements - only scripts exists but not database

Tags: mysql, database, coding-style, refactoring-databases

I have script (.sql) files ready to create a database (create schema, procedures, add test data).

I also have coding standards/conventions to be set against those scripts.

*Ex: Table name should not end with "_tbl", All the SQL keywords (SELECT, UPDATE, FROM) should be in caps.*

Is there a best/Easy way to rename these (according to coding standards I have) such that When I rename a database object, other objects that reference the renamed object should automatically updated with the new name

[Found few links to serve this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833295(v=vs.100).aspx). But would like to confirm is this the best & easy approach. Or any better way than this..

*For example, if I rename a column in a table, any stored procedures that reference that column are automatically updated with the new name.*

NOTE:Also please comment about tool for MySQL scripts if its different from tool for SQL scripts

Many thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

Changing a column name does not update stored procedures that reference it.

```
CREATE TABLE t ( v char(1) );
INSERT INTO t SET v='x';

CREATE PROCEDURE p() 
  SELECT v FROM t;

CALL p();
+------+
| v    |
+------+
| x    |
+------+

ALTER TABLE t CHANGE COLUMN v v2 CHAR(1);

CALL p();
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'v' in 'field list'
```

A similar problem exists for views.

I think the best option is to edit your SQL scripts with a text editor and do search & replace for all instances of the table names you want to change. Update all instances manually with the text editor. Then run the SQL scripts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. [then this tool is for what?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833295(v=vs.100).aspx). You mean this refactoring cannot be done by any tool?

Comment: Essentially, that tool does what @billkarwin suggests. It updates the other files. IOW, it's not done on the SQL side, but on the source file side of things.

Comment: @Sloan Thrasher Can you please put some light on this.(elaborate)

Comment: @Vinni, the link you give is for Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL. There's a list of useful community tools for MySQL at http://shlomi-noach.github.io/awesome-mysql/ but none of them do the task you describe. I've never heard of one that does.